# How can I create a filter in Active Directory to show only 'Enabled' Computer Accounts

Tags: active-directory, domain-controller

Please note: I am referring to COMPUTER accounts. Not USER accounts.

In Active Directory, it is easy to create a filter to show only Disabled Computer Accounts by ticking the box "Disabled Accounts" in the Query setup windows as per below.

[image]

This creates the following query:

> (&(objectCategory=computer)(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2))

How can I create a filter to do the exact opposite? I.e. I want to see only ENABLED accounts.

Answer (score 4):

The query is a simple LDAP-Query, so you can use the negation operator: just place a ! in front of the item, and the outcome will be negated.
So in your case:

```
(&(objectCategory=computer)(!userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2))
```

I tested this query in my AD. Without the exclemation mark, i get only 4 computer accounts which are disabled. With the exclemation mark, i get all the other computer accounts, except the ones that are disabled.

Comment: You may need to wrap the `!` Operator in an additional set of `( )` to work!
At least Apache Directory Studio complains about incorrect filter syntax.

This should work `(&(objectCategory=computer)(!(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)))`